# Hydraulic scissor jack lifting capacity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, pressure

Can you please assist with a really simple question?

I have a hydraulic scissor jack table with  the following: 2 hydraulic cylinders, each with a cylinder stroke of 240mm, a cylinder bore of 50mm and a hydraulic pressure of 15Mpa.

I need to calculate the lifting capacity of this table (ignoring the mass of the components).

The rams drive a center pin of the scissor mechanism.

I'm trying to approach this from two directions, either Fx=w/tan (theta) or P=mgh/Al.

I've hit a blank - any clarity?

Comment: A diagram would help clarify the question...

Answer (score 1):

The force that each of the pistons can drive with is given by

$$F=\frac14 \pi d^2 P$$

How much lift that produces depends on the exact geometry of the table and in general will be a function of height. In essence if the table moves $x_1$ when the pistons move $x_2$ the force will be

$$F_{table}=2F_{piston}\frac{x_2}{x_1}$$